# Настройка apache + modssl для работы через https в Windows

Tags: apache, https

Доброго времени! Как произвести настройку для работы через https в Windows?

Comment: @archik, если Вам помог ответ - жмакните по галке слева под кулчаком вниз. ![alt text][1]  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/Qe5BY.png(взято из ответа @shaman888)

Answer (score 1):

Поставить [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), настроить https [так](http://buduguru.ru/podgotovka-1-ustanavlivaem-server-xampp/) или [так](http://www.iconsun.ru/2010/07/xampp-windows.html). Не забыть, что понадобится сертификат.